# Do antidepressants cause brain damage?

Tags: neurology, medications, depression

A friend two years ago read an online article that claims antidepressants cause brain damage. I don't know which one, but I imagine it was something like [this](http://www.toxicpsychiatry.com/antidepressant-brain-damage).

Do antidepressants cause brain damage?

Comment: related: does depression cause brain damage?

Answer (score 4):

[The article you refer to](http://www.toxicpsychiatry.com/antidepressant-brain-damage) seems biased and misleading. It quotes multiple serious-looking papers, then reaches a conclusion not mentioned in any of them.

Several articles (e.g. [this](http://www.toxicpsychiatry.com/storage/Antidep%20Duration%20of%20Treatment%20Risk%20of%20New%20Depress%20Verdoux%202011.pdf) and [this](http://www.toxicpsychiatry.com/storage/antidep%20El-Mallakh-tardivedysphoriadarticle1.pdf)) claim that anti-depressants are not so efficient in curing depression - after you stop taking them, depression often returns.
One article reports a correlation between depression and later dementia. It doesn't mention anti-depressants.

The nearest thing to brain damage I could find is claims that anti-depressants cause the body to build tolerance, so after you stop using them the depression may be worse than before.

Comment: "several articles" - which articles? "One article" - be specific. "claims that anti-depressants cause the body to build tolerance" - specify your source. "depression may be worse than before" - says who?

Comment: @Jamiec, It's all in the articles referred in the page. I now added some specific references.

Answer (score 0):

Anti-depressants are medications targeting neurotransmitters in the brain. They don´t cause brain damage, quite opposite, they help the brain restore its function after damage, as occurs in stroke ([escitalopram enhances cognition after stroke](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3718472/))

Comment: Sorry, I don't find this answer provides enough evidence.